# Jmeter - How to pass arrary of Json strings in parameters

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

Trying to test an API which accepts array of JSON formatted strings. 
I am passing the array in http post request but am getting response as JSON parse exception because the api is splitting the array after a key-value pair. i.e. when it finds a comma but I want each JSON objects as a string so that it can be mapped.
I am passing something like this:

```
array[] : {"name":"name1","adrs":"address1"},{"name":"name2","adrs":"address2"}
```

And in my API I want this two objects as two string in `array[] param`, but instead it is showing like 4 elements in array param.

Comment: there is stringify method in javaScript use it

Comment: Thanx for reply.Stringify I am using when I am calling the API from javascript using ajax. But I am not getting how to do it in jmeter.